# Getting command line flags from snakemake

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, snakemake

Is it possible to retrieve the flags used on the command line? For example, I want to force the use conda for my workflow, as I have set up environments for various rules. This allows me to control package versions, and users don't have to install packages manually. This is what I would like to do:

When on the command line, I use this command:
`snakemake --cores 10`

I can then detect the usage of these flags. For example:

```py
if snakemake.flags.use_conda == False:
    print("You must use conda!")
    exit(1)
```

I know this isn't exactly perfect, but I hope my intentions are clear.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
if not workflow.use_conda:
    sys.stderr.write("Use conda\n")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Note that `sys.exit` makes snakemake give an ugly error trace - I vaguely remember a hacky workaround which I cannot find now...

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I'm not super worried about `sys.exit`, especially since I can throw my own errors into the `sys.stderr.write` line.